# Python server not responding

Tags: python, sockets

I'm very new to sockets, so I was just trying to get a simple server/client system running.

My server.py:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 5555))
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(2048)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf.decode())
        break
```

My client.py:

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(("192.168.1.157", 5555))
msg = str.encode(input('Enter your message: '))
clientsocket.send(msg)
```

When I run both codes on my laptop, it works: the server receives the message and then closes. However, when I run the client on my desktop, I get a `'TimeoutError [WinError 10060]'`. I've tried `serversocket.bind(('0.0.0.0',5555))` as well, with the same results. The other IP addresses that I've tried, such as the one I get from sites like www.whatismyip.com just give `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]`.  I have no idea what's wrong, although I imagine its something to do with the IP address being wrong, but I can't find anything online that actually helps.

Comment: Are you sure the port you're requesting on your desktop isn't forbidden?

Comment: If you're trying to run the server on your laptop and the client on your desktop, what other network infrastructure is between them? I imagine at least a router, right? Is it running a firewall (probably yes)? If so, how is it configured?

Comment: When running the client on a different machine, are you changing the ip address in the client code?

Comment: I've tried other ports, I'm not changing the ip address, and yeah there's a router - how would I see how that and the firewall are configured?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same network, you should use the local ip address to connect to the server. It is usually 10.0.1.x or something similar. You can find it by running `ipconfig /all`(I think) if on windows, and `ifconfig` or `ip address` on linux. You should look for anything that says `ipv4 address`, or `inet` in the output.

Comment: I can't find anything like that. The ip I used was the IPv4 address under 'Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi' - it was the only one that I tried that worked properly on my laptop.